# Azure Pipeline - Passing Variables between tasks

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-pipelines, azure-pipelines-tasks

All,

I have the below Azure DevOps pipeline setup that copy keyvault secrets from one KV to another.  As you can see, I have two tasks: 1) one to read the secrets and 2) one to write the secrets.  I am having difficulties figuring out how to pass the "***$secrets***" variable (thru "***echo "##vso[task.setVariable variable=sourceSecrets]$json***") from the first task to the second task.

```
stages:
  - stage: "Test1"
    displayName: "Test1 - Copy KV"
    jobs:
    - deployment : "Deploy"
      timeoutInMinutes: 120
      variables:
        sourceSecrets: ""
      strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
              - task: AzureCLI@2
                inputs:
                  azureSubscription: $(ServiceConnection1)
                  scriptType: 'pscore'
                  scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
                  inlineScript: |
                          if ("$(mysubscription1)"){
                              az account set --subscription "mysubscription1"
                          }

                          $secNames = az keyvault secret list --vault-name "kvName1"  -o json --query "[].name"  | ConvertFrom-Json

                          Write-Host 'Reading secrets...'
                          $secrets = $secNames | % {
                              $secret = az keyvault secret show --name $_ --vault-name "kvName1" -o json | ConvertFrom-Json
                              [PSCustomObject]@{
                                  name  = $_;
                                  value = $secret.value;
                              } 
                          }
                          $json = $($secrets | ConvertTo-Json)
                          echo "##vso[task.setVariable variable=sourceSecrets]$json"
                          
              - task: AzureCLI@2
                inputs:
                  azureSubscription: $(ServiceConnection2)
                  scriptType: 'pscore'
                  scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
                  inlineScript: |
                          if ("$(mysubscription2)"){
                              az account set --subscription $(mysubscription2)
                          }
                          $secrets = "$(sourceSecrets)" | ConvertFrom-Json
                          $secrets.foreach{
                          Write-Host 'Writing secrets:'
                              az keyvault secret set --vault-name $(kvName2) --name $_.name  --value  $_.value --output none
                              Write-Host '---->' $_.name
                          }
```

When the pipeline executes, tasks one executes fine.  However, the 2nd task errored out with the following:

```
ConvertFrom-Json : Conversion from JSON failed with error: Error reading JArray from JsonReader. Path '', line 1, position 1.
At /home/vsts/work/_temp/azureclitaskscript1620360635888_inlinescript.ps1:4 char:18
+ $secrets = "[" | ConvertFrom-Json
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand
```

I did some checking, it appears the $(sourceSecrets) variable contain only "[" instead of the entire json content.  This means the "***echo "##vso[task.setVariable variable=sourceSecrets]$json***" line from the first task is excluding everything after "[".  I can't figure out why it is doing that.  Ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this will help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55617951/how-do-i-copy-over-all-secrets-from-one-azure-keyvault-to-another-using-powershe

Comment: Ended up taking another approach and fixed the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46306467/powershell-json-formatting

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the value of the pipeline variable only supports string type, and should be a single line string. If you pass a multi-line content to a pipeline variable, normally only the first line will be received as the value of the variable.

In your case, the value you pass to the variable is a JSON object that contains multi-line content.

To avoid the issue you are facing, you should convert the content of the JSON object to be a single line string before passing it to the pipeline variable.

To convert a multi-line string to be a single line string, you can try the command lines below:

```sh
. . .

# escape '%', '\n' and '\r'
json="${json//'%'/'%25'}"
json="${json//$'\n'/'%0A'}"
json="${json//$'\r'/'%0D'}"

echo "##vso[task.setVariable variable=sourceSecrets]$json"
```

Comment: Hi Bright Ran.  Thanks for the comment.  Not familiar with the commands you've mention.  I've tried the below but  the variable is empty.  Can you please clarify?  Thanks

```
$json="${$json//'%'/'%25'}"
$json="${$json//$'\n'/'%0A'}"
$json="${$json//$'\r'/'%0D'}"
```